# Carrierwave file delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Again I need your help. Now I need to understand how I can delete with Carrierwave uploaded files (in my case - images).

***models/attachment.rb :***

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :file, :file
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

***models/post.rb :***

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :attachments_attributes, :_destroy
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

***views/posts/_form.html.erb :***

```
<%= nested_form_for @post, :html=>{:multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="field">
    <%= f.label :Nosaukums %>:<br /><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="field">
    <%= f.label :Raksts %>:<br /><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br /><br />
  </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |attachment| %>
    <% if attachment.object.new_record? %>
      <%= attachment.file_field :file %>

    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag(attachment.object.file.url) %>
      <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>


    <%= f.submit "Publicēt", :id => "button-link" %>
<% end %>
```

When I am trying to delete previous uploaded file I have this error:

```
unknown attribute: _destroy
```

Maybe there is problem because I have multiple file uploads not only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the method on the wrong model. Your file mount is on the Attachment.

The error is telling you what is wrong.

```
undefined method 'remove_file' for #<Post:0x471a320
```

The key point of the error is the method is being called on the Post model when it needs to be called on the Attachment model.

Maybe try scoping the input for the checkbox to the correct model.

```
<%= attachment.check_box :remove_file %>
```

Answer (score 12):

None of this worked for me, but after digging I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447127/carrierwave-cannot-remove-image?rq=1) that really helped. Basically...

Form (where **f** is your form objects):

```
<%= f.check_box :remove_image %>
```

Then, if you check the box and submit the form you'll get the following error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: remove_image

Which is easily solved by simply adding `remove_image` to your `attr_accessible` list on the model. In the end it'll look something like:

```
class Background < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :remove_image
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :image, BackgroundUploader
end
```

In my case it's a background image that belongs to the user. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thx for the tip! I got it working by adding :remove_image to my controller params.required('my_object').permit(:remove_image) method

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files), the checkbox should be called `remove_file`.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this, but when I am trying `remove_file` I have this error: `undefined method 'remove_file' for #<Post:0x471a320>`

Comment: You are trying to call the method `remove_file`? According to the docs the method is called `remove_file!` (note the exclamation mark).

Answer (score 3):

It should be
**<%= attachment.check_box :_destroy%>**

It works for me